# gson array parsing

Tags: android, gson

how to parse

```
{
    "urls": [
        "http://www.url.com",
        "http://www.url.com",
        "http://www.url.com",
        "http://www.url.com",
        "http://www.url.com"
    ]
}
```

using gson?
Ill always parse the string in the format :

```
{
        "urls": [
            x:"http://www.url.com",
            x:"http://www.url.com",
            x: "http://www.url.com",
            x: "http://www.url.com",
            x: "http://www.url.com"
        ]
    }
```

how to parse the string if the name of the variable (x in this case) is not included?

Comment: Show code how you parsed it up to this moment.

Answer (score 1):

It can be parsed as an `Object` that has only one field `urls` which is of type `String[]`.  In other words,

```
class UrlList {
    String[] urls;
}
```

Assuming you put the text in a `String` named `gsonText`, you can parse it with

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
UrlList uList = gson.fromJson(gsonText, UrlList.class);
```